# Cronjob to run after every 30 minutes from a specific time

Tags: cron

If my cron job runs first at suppose 9:15. Then how do I make it run after every 30 minutes from then at 9:45 then 10:15 and so on?

Comment: This is not a programming related question, which makes it off-topic here. My suggestion would be that you ask it at [unix.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
15,45 9-23 * * *
```

This should give you “At minute 15 and 45 past every hour from 9 through 23.” (according to: https://crontab.guru/#15,45_9-23_*_*_*)